# Why is my Wi-Fi constantly in use?

Tags: wifi, android

I have a nexus phone running android lollipop. Even if I'm not browsing the web or using the WiFi at all (and after sync of various components has completed) the WiFi up/down arrows still flash periodically.

What is using the Wi-Fi? **and** is there any way for me to check what specifically is using the Wi-Fi?

Comment: Chrome, usually. It'll kill your battery too. Google analytics iirc

Comment: This has nothing to do with security?

Answer (score 1):

While your phone is connected to the Wifi it will be subject to DHCP requests in order to maintain a connection.

So while your mobile device is connected to the router it will periodically send & receive ARP packets. It is likely that it would also respond to other simple requests, such as ping from other devices, network discovery from other machines etc.

Answer (score 0):

Most programs that constantly check for updates will check in the background over wifi even if the application is not open. Applications such as facebook messenger do this often to get near realtime updates.

Comment: I disabled sync through the settings -> accounts option and still the WiFi up/down arrows continue to flash?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean (I don't use android), but in this [image,](http://www.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/postimages/684/accounts-sync.png) it also shows a background data box. That could be it.

Comment: If that doesn't stop it, you might be able to find the process that's causing it using a program similar to [TCPview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) but for android, or by using wireshark to try to infer what app it is.